# SQL to return for every project most recent updated date in JIRA

Tags: sql, jira

Well I am hosting more than 100 projects in JIRA and want to know which of these projects are active.
So found some SQL query related to that that can give the list of all projects with last day of updation.

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.PROJECT, MIN(i.UPDATED) as "Last Updated", p.pname
FROM jiraissue i
INNER JOIN project p
ON p.ID = i.PROJECT
GROUP BY i.PROJECT, p.pname
ORDER BY MIN(i.UPDATED) ASC, i.PROJECT, p.pname
```

But not getting the desired result. 
So any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: How would u find the active project is there any status flag ?

Comment: Well my requirement is just that I want a list of my all projects with last date of updation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you just want to get the last updated projects use `MAX()` function instead of `MIN()` and do the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
        i.PROJECT, MAX(i.UPDATED) as "Last Updated", MAX(p.pname) Name
FROM jiraissue i
INNER JOIN project p
ON p.ID = i.PROJECT
GROUP BY i.PROJECT
ORDER BY 2,1,3
```

Comment: Well thank you so much. It worked as required.  Moreover can we use this query with some modification to List all the Project Keys related to the projects that have been listed out earlier.

Comment: @SandeepAnand... `Project Keys` what means ? could you explore bit more with some sample data.

Comment: Sir, while creating some projects in JIRA we get some keys for example for project-  3M MES Testing, we have keys like TST. So by the term "project Keys" i meant of "TST"

Comment: @SandeepAnand... So, the one project has multiple Keys or One ?

Comment: one project has only one key

Comment: @SandeepAnand... great than use `max(key)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166802/discussion-between-yogesh-sharma-and-sandeep-anand).